# Obtener un registro hasheado y almacenarlo en una variable para usarla con Password_verify

Tags: php, sql, mvc, model-view-controller

Buen día a todos, soy nuevo en la programación con PHP y actualmente me encuentro estudiándolo, pero me he encontrado con un problema (de lógica, al parecer) que no puedo resolver.

Estoy utilizando un sistema MVC y dentro de él, estoy implementando usuarios. En la parte de registro todo lo he hecho bien, la parte que me falla es poder hacer la validación en un **Login**. El problema es, que para hashear la password, he utilizado la función **password_hash()** que incluye PHP, y debido a esto, no he podido hacer la validación para poder loguear a algún usuario. Esto a causa de que para "validar" la contraseña ingresada con la almacenada en la base de datos se utiliza una función llamada **"Password_verify"**, que consta de dos parámetros, los cuáles son la contraseña ingresada directamente, y la segunda, la contraseña hasheada(la que se registró en la base de datos).
Ahora bien que ya expliqué el contexto, les muestro mi supuesta "lógica" que utilizo pero no me funciona.

**Modelo Login**

```
class LoginModel extends Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function login($usuario)
    {
        try {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = $usuario";
            $resultado = $this->query($query);
            $resultado->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);

            $valor = $resultado->fetchAll();

            return $valor;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    }
```

En donde recibo un parámentro, que en este caso sería el nombre de usuario que se ingresa, posteriormente hago la consulta y creo una variable que guarde todo lo obtenido en dicha consulta y al final retorno esa variable.

**Controlador Login**

```
function validarUsuario(){
    $usuario = isset($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
    
    $usuariosRegistrados = $this->model->login($usuario);

    $passwordbd = $usuariosRegistrados['password'];
        
    if(password_verify($password,$passwordbd['password'])){
        $mensaje = "Sesion iniciada";
        $tipoMensaje = "alert alert-success";
    }else{
        $mensaje = "Error";
        $tipoMensaje = "alert alert-danger";
    }
    $this->view->mensaje = $mensaje;
    $this->view->tipoMensaje = $tipoMensaje;
    $this->render();
}
```

En esta función obtengo y valido directamente del formulario creado, después en la variable  $usuariosRegistrados supuestamente "obtengo" lo que me habría retornado la función "login" creada en el modelo, y continúo creando una variable que me obtenga la columna "password" que se supone tendría que haber obtenido con el query en el modelo. Hago una condición utilizando **Password_verify** para comprobar que la contraseña ingresada y la hasheada con **password_hash** sean las mismas y únicamente mando un mensaje de éxito o de lo contrario de error. Al hacer pruebas siempre me manda el tipo de mensaje de error(el que se muestra en el código), imprimí el supuesto "resultado" del campo password y solo me muestra una "S", lo que se me hace raro porque tendría que regresarme un Boolean según la documentación de PHP.

*Nota: En el modelo uso solo "query($query)" debido a que en "acorté" de esta forma para no escribirlo todo:

```
  function query($query)
    {
        return $this->db->connect()->query($query);
    }
```

Gracias de antemano y disculpen por escribir demasiado texto. Espero no estár tan alejado de la lógica correcta, aunque de ser lo contrario, agradecería mucho me hicieran notar los errores que tengo, y cómo podría solucionarlos, gracias nuevamente.

Update: al hacer un var_dump de ***$usuariosRegistrados['password']*** el resultado es: ***string(1) "S"***

Comment: Podrias hacer un ```var_dump($resultado)```  para ver como están los datos y que es lo que obtienes, esta bien que escribas bastante, si el problema lo requiere, ya que das más detalles

Comment: El resultado que me muestra el var_dump es: string(1) "S"

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás usando [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) que devuelve un arreglo con todos los registros encontrados o arreglo vacío en caso de que no haya coincidencias.

Como esperas un solo resultado, podrías usar solo [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), que devuelve el registro encontrado o falso si no se encontró:

```
function login($usuario)
{
    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = $usuario";
        $resultado = $this->prepare($query);
        $resultado->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
        // Ejecutar consulta
        $resultado->execute();

        // No es necesario asignar a una variable
        return $resultado->fetch();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Después, validas el resultado antes de verificar la contraseña:

```
function validarUsuario(){
    $usuario = isset($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
    
    $usuariosRegistrados = $this->model->login($usuario);
    // Validas que hay registro
    if($usuariosRegistrados === false) {
        // No se encontró el usuario
        $mensaje = "Error";
        $tipoMensaje = "alert alert-danger";
    } else {
        // Ahora sí puedes verificar la contraseña
        $passwordbd = $usuariosRegistrados['password'];
        
        if(password_verify($password,$passwordbd['password'])){
            $mensaje = "Sesion iniciada";
            $tipoMensaje = "alert alert-success";
        }else{
            $mensaje = "Error";
            $tipoMensaje = "alert alert-danger";
        }
    }
    $this->view->mensaje = $mensaje;
    $this->view->tipoMensaje = $tipoMensaje;
    $this->render();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la he puesto en práctica pero lastimosamente sigue sin funcionar. Sigue mandandome error. Al tratar de imprimir el valor que obtengo de la bd, me sigue mostrando una "S". no sé a qué se deba realmente.

Comment: Sí, no me di cuenta que faltaba [ejecutar la consulta](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php): `$resultado->execute();` antes de leer.

Comment: Ya resolví el problema y en efecto, me faltaba el execute. He modificado un poco y me ha ido bien, ahora tengo otro problema, que es el password_verify, te dejo el enlace con mas detalles, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda. 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443520/problema-con-password-verify

Comment: De hecho, había que cambiar `$this->query(...)` por `$this->prepare(...)`, porque la primera ejecuta la consulta y ya no permite enlazar parámetros.